# How to insert a svg map in a php file

Tags: php, svg, maps

So, i have a map in svg. I tried to put it in the php file of my website. I have inserted:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="315px" height="465px" version="1.1">
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Map" cursor="pointer">
```

And then the path. But i can´t make the map change color when i move the mouser over the map. I have already seen a lot of website, but i can´t put it working, i don´t know why. Can you help???

Code:

```
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/theme/map.svgz" class="map" id="map1">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="315px" height="465px" version="1.1">
            <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Mapa de Portugal" cursor="pointer">
                    <path id="Viana do Castelo" d="M175,2 C170,3 167,6 164,7 C160,8 156,7 154,8 C152,8 152,10 151,10 C149,10 148,9 146,10 C144,11 143,13 143,13 C143,13 131,25 130,26 C129,28 129,29 129,33 C129,36 129,36 130,39 C132,44 133,49 133,49 C133,49 139,47 145,46 C149,46 148,48 151,47 C154,46 152,45 152,41 C158,37 156,36 167,35 C175,34 179,30 179,30 C179,30 179,28 178,26 C177,25 175,25 175,23 C175,20 175,20 177,17 C178,15 180,15 181,14 C182,12 182,13 183,11 C183,7 179,8 176,8 C176,4 176,3 175,2 Z M175,2" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Braga" d="M133,49 C133,49 139,47 145,46 C149,46 148,48 151,47 C154,46 152,45 152,41 C158,37 156,36 167,35 C175,34 179,30 179,30 C179,30 181,32 182,32 C183,32 186,32 186,32 C186,32 180,40 182,41 C183,42 187,41 187,41 C187,41 189,49 191,50 C193,51 195,52 195,52 C195,52 199,50 200,51 C202,52 199,55 199,55 C199,55 194,63 192,65 C191,68 191,72 191,72 C191,72 189,74 186,74 C182,75 182,72 176,68 C171,69 154,72 150,72 C145,72 147,69 144,66 C142,64 142,63 140,62 C138,62 136,63 135,62 C134,61 135,59 135,56 C134,53 133,49 133,49" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Porto" d="M191,72 C191,72 189,74 186,74 C182,75 182,72 176,68 C171,69 154,72 150,72 C145,72 147,69 144,66 C142,64 142,63 140,62 C138,62 136,63 135,62 C134,61 136,64 136,65 C136,66 135,67 135,67 C135,67 137,72 138,77 C139,82 140,87 140,87 C140,87 142,89 143,90 C143,92 143,94 143,94 C143,94 143,96 144,98 C144,100 144,102 144,102 C144,102 152,102 154,101 C157,101 156,99 157,99 C159,99 159,103 161,102 C163,100 164,98 167,98 C169,97 172,98 172,98 C172,98 177,96 185,95 C194,94 196,92 196,92 C196,92 197,85 196,81 C195,77 191,72 191,72" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Aveiro" d="M144,102 C144,102 152,102 154,101 C157,101 156,99 157,99 C159,99 159,103 161,102 C163,100 164,98 167,98 C169,97 172,98 172,98 C172,98 173,102 176,104 C179,106 179,106 182,106 C180,112 183,111 179,117 C178,118 173,118 173,118 C173,118 167,129 167,132 C167,134 169,136 170,138 C170,140 168,139 168,141 C168,144 170,144 170,147 C169,149 167,149 166,151 C165,155 165,159 165,159 C165,159 158,168 156,168 C153,168 153,167 153,165 C153,163 155,162 155,160 C156,158 149,155 148,154 C148,152 150,150 148,150 C147,150 146,155 144,154 C141,153 136,149 135,147 C134,144 138,135 139,135 C140,135 141,137 142,137 C143,137 143,135 143,134 C143,133 141,134 141,133 C141,132 142,131 143,130 C144,128 146,129 146,128 C146,126 141,129 143,125 C144,120 146,120 146,119 C146,118 143,120 143,120 L138,133 C138,133 137,132 138,130 C139,127 143,109 144,106 C144,104 144,102 144,102 Z M144,102" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Coimbra" d="M165,159 C165,159 158,168 156,168 C153,168 153,167 153,165 C153,163 155,162 155,160 C156,158 149,155 148,154 C148,152 150,150 148,150 C147,150 146,155 144,154 C141,153 136,149 135,147 C135,145 134,154 132,161 C130,168 128,173 127,175 C126,179 130,179 130,179 C130,179 135,181 135,182 C136,183 130,181 129,181 C128,182 127,189 127,189 C127,189 134,190 140,190 C145,190 145,193 147,193 C148,193 147,191 149,191 C151,191 151,196 153,196 C155,196 156,191 159,192 C161,193 162,198 164,199 C167,200 168,198 169,194 C170,187 173,187 176,187 C178,187 180,190 180,193 C181,197 180,199 180,199 C180,199 206,185 207,184 C208,183 203,180 203,177 C203,174 204,172 204,172 C204,172 202,171 202,167 C202,164 204,163 204,161 C203,158 200,155 200,155 C200,155 202,154 202,152 C203,151 201,148 201,148 C201,148 197,151 189,157 C182,163 180,163 175,163 C170,164 165,159 165,159 Z M165,159" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Leiria" d="M127,189 C127,189 134,190 140,190 C145,190 145,193 147,193 C148,193 147,191 149,191 C151,191 151,196 153,196 C155,196 156,191 159,192 C161,193 162,198 164,199 C167,200 168,198 169,194 C170,187 173,187 176,187 C178,187 180,190 180,193 C181,197 180,199 180,199 C180,199 181,201 178,203 C175,206 173,206 171,207 C169,209 169,212 169,212 C169,212 166,214 161,214 C157,214 156,208 154,208 C152,208 149,210 146,213 C143,215 143,216 143,218 C142,220 144,221 144,222 C144,224 140,234 138,237 C137,240 131,239 128,240 C126,241 122,247 121,249 C120,252 120,255 120,255 C120,255 118,254 115,256 C112,257 111,260 109,261 C108,261 106,259 106,259 C106,259 107,255 103,254 C102,253 100,257 97,257 C97,254 94,252 93,251 C92,249 96,251 99,249 C102,248 103,245 103,245 C103,245 104,248 105,248 C106,248 107,248 107,247 C107,245 105,243 105,243 C105,243 114,234 115,230 C115,227 115,226 117,219 C119,211 127,189 127,189 Z M127,189" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Lisboa" d="M120,255 C120,255 118,254 115,256 C112,257 111,260 109,261 C108,261 106,259 106,259 C106,259 107,255 103,254 C102,253 100,257 97,257 C97,254 97,260 96,265 C94,270 92,271 91,276 C90,281 91,281 91,286 C91,292 89,294 87,299 C88,305 87,308 88,309 C88,310 92,309 94,310 C97,310 96,311 98,311 C101,311 98,310 102,310 C106,309 107,310 111,308 C115,307 113,305 114,301 C114,297 115,298 117,294 C118,291 119,289 120,289 C121,289 121,293 122,294 C122,295 123,296 123,296 C123,296 121,300 125,291 C129,283 131,281 132,278 C133,276 134,276 132,272 C130,268 127,268 127,267 C127,266 133,266 133,264 C132,262 129,263 125,261 C121,258 120,255 120,255 Z M120,255" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Bragança" d="M244,26 C244,26 245,28 245,32 C245,36 241,51 239,56 C237,60 235,61 234,64 C233,68 234,71 232,77 C231,82 228,85 228,85 C228,85 230,87 232,89 C234,91 236,92 236,92 C236,92 240,92 242,92 C243,92 243,93 245,92 C246,92 247,89 248,89 C249,89 249,90 251,94 C253,99 254,100 256,101 C258,101 262,101 262,101 C262,101 267,101 269,101 C271,100 273,97 273,97 C273,97 272,94 275,90 C279,86 279,85 281,83 C283,82 285,82 288,81 C291,80 293,78 295,76 C298,74 299,70 300,69 C301,68 302,69 304,68 C305,66 305,64 306,62 C307,59 311,55 313,52 C311,49 311,49 309,48 C308,46 308,45 305,44 C302,43 302,43 298,43 C295,43 295,44 290,43 C288,43 288,40 288,36 C288,32 290,32 290,29 C290,26 289,27 288,24 C288,20 289,19 288,18 C286,18 282,20 279,20 C276,20 273,16 272,16 C271,16 271,20 265,20 C263,20 262,18 260,18 C257,18 257,19 255,19 C252,19 251,15 248,16 C245,16 245,16 245,18 C245,19 245,20 245,22 C245,24 244,26 244,26" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Vila Real" d="M244,26 C244,26 245,28 245,32 C245,36 241,51 239,56 C237,60 235,61 234,64 C233,68 234,71 232,77 C231,82 228,85 228,85 C228,85 228,87 221,88 C217,89 213,89 209,90 C202,91 196,92 196,92 C196,92 197,85 196,81 C195,77 191,72 191,72 C191,72 191,68 192,65 C194,63 199,55 199,55 C199,55 202,52 200,51 C199,50 195,52 195,52 C195,52 193,51 191,50 C189,49 187,41 187,41 C187,41 183,42 182,41 C180,40 186,32 186,32 C186,32 188,28 190,27 C192,25 192,26 194,25 C195,24 195,21 197,22 C198,25 197,26 198,27 C199,27 204,23 208,23 C213,23 216,24 216,27 C216,30 218,30 218,30 C218,30 220,29 222,28 C223,27 223,26 224,26 C227,26 227,31 229,31 C232,32 230,28 235,28 C240,28 244,26 244,26 Z M244,26" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Guarda" d="M236,92 C236,92 240,92 242,92 C243,92 243,93 245,92 C246,92 247,89 248,89 C249,89 249,90 251,94 C253,99 254,100 256,101 C258,101 262,101 262,101 C262,101 264,103 267,107 C268,108 269,111 269,113 C270,114 270,115 271,116 C272,119 269,121 270,124 C270,126 270,129 271,132 C272,135 270,140 270,141 C270,143 271,144 271,148 C271,152 269,150 269,154 C270,158 274,160 272,162 C271,163 268,165 268,168 C268,171 262,171 261,171 C259,171 260,168 259,168 C256,167 255,169 254,169 C253,169 253,167 251,167 C249,166 249,169 246,169 C244,169 240,172 236,168 C235,166 239,159 238,158 C237,157 235,157 232,157 C228,158 227,158 225,159 C223,161 216,167 211,169 C206,172 204,172 204,172 C204,172 202,171 202,167 C202,164 204,163 204,161 C203,158 200,155 200,155 C200,155 202,154 202,152 C203,151 201,148 201,148 C201,148 210,145 214,142 C218,139 218,138 219,132 C219,127 214,123 215,120 C215,117 217,116 220,116 C223,115 225,119 227,119 C228,116 228,114 230,111 C232,109 233,110 234,109 C232,105 233,104 233,99 C234,95 236,92 236,92 Z M236,92" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Viseu" d="M228,85 C228,85 230,87 232,89 C234,90 236,92 236,92 C236,92 235,94 234,99 C233,104 232,105 234,109 C234,110 232,109 230,111 C228,114 229,116 227,119 C225,119 223,116 220,116 C217,116 216,117 215,120 C215,123 219,127 219,132 C218,138 218,139 214,142 C210,145 201,148 201,148 C201,148 198,151 190,157 C183,163 180,163 175,164 C170,164 164,160 164,160 C164,160 165,154 166,151 C167,148 169,149 170,147 C170,144 168,144 168,141 C168,138 170,139 170,138 C169,136 167,134 167,131 C167,129 173,117 173,117 C173,117 178,118 179,116 C183,111 180,112 182,106 C179,106 178,106 175,104 C173,102 172,98 172,98 C172,98 177,95 185,94 C194,94 196,92 196,92 C196,92 202,90 209,89 C213,89 217,89 221,88 C228,87 228,85 228,85 L228,85 Z M228,85" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Castelo Branco" d="M169,211 C169,211 170,208 171,207 C173,205 176,205 178,203 C181,200 180,199 180,199 C180,199 206,185 207,184 C208,183 203,179 203,177 C203,174 204,172 204,172 C204,172 207,171 211,169 C216,166 223,161 225,159 C227,158 228,157 232,157 C235,157 237,157 238,158 C239,159 235,166 236,168 C240,172 244,169 247,169 C249,169 249,166 251,166 C253,167 253,168 254,169 C256,169 256,167 259,168 C260,168 260,170 261,170 C262,171 259,171 258,173 C256,175 256,177 256,179 C256,181 260,183 262,184 C263,185 264,187 266,191 C266,196 265,195 264,198 C264,201 264,203 263,205 C262,206 259,210 258,213 C258,215 258,219 257,221 C255,223 254,223 250,223 C246,223 244,223 240,223 C237,223 238,224 234,224 C230,224 229,223 226,223 C224,223 221,224 221,224 C221,224 217,224 214,225 C210,226 201,233 201,233 C201,233 201,229 199,227 C197,225 196,226 194,223 C191,220 193,216 189,216 C185,216 185,217 185,220 C184,222 184,226 180,227 C177,229 175,225 174,223 C173,221 169,211 169,211 Z M169,211" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Portalegre" d="M221,224 C221,224 217,224 214,225 C210,226 201,233 201,233 C201,233 201,236 199,235 C197,235 199,233 194,233 C190,233 188,236 188,239 C188,242 190,242 190,245 C190,248 188,251 186,252 C184,254 174,263 174,263 C174,263 166,265 166,272 C166,280 175,282 175,282 C175,282 177,281 179,281 C181,281 181,283 183,283 C185,284 185,283 186,284 C187,284 187,286 190,287 C194,288 194,286 196,287 C199,288 196,291 201,291 C206,292 211,289 211,289 C211,289 222,283 224,284 C224,284 225,288 227,291 C229,295 231,300 235,300 C239,300 240,297 241,297 C242,297 242,298 242,299 C242,300 241,301 241,302 C241,303 243,304 243,304 C243,304 247,301 249,300 C251,298 252,298 253,296 C255,293 256,290 257,287 C258,284 260,285 260,279 C260,274 256,272 254,272 C252,272 252,273 250,272 C248,272 249,273 247,268 C246,263 244,266 242,264 C241,262 241,260 241,260 C241,260 242,258 240,255 C238,252 235,252 236,250 C237,247 237,244 237,242 C237,240 233,240 228,234 C223,227 221,224 221,224 Z M221,224" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Évora" d="M175,282 C175,282 177,281 179,281 C181,281 181,283 183,283 C185,284 185,283 186,284 C187,284 187,286 190,287 C194,288 194,286 196,287 C199,288 196,291 201,291 C206,292 211,289 211,289 C211,289 222,283 224,284 C224,284 225,288 227,291 C229,295 231,300 235,300 C239,300 240,297 241,297 C242,297 242,298 242,299 C242,300 241,301 241,302 C241,303 243,304 243,304 C243,304 239,307 239,311 C239,314 240,313 240,316 C240,319 236,325 236,327 C236,330 235,332 237,334 C239,336 242,339 245,344 C248,349 250,355 250,355 C250,355 251,356 247,356 C243,356 245,352 243,350 C242,348 241,344 236,344 C232,344 227,352 222,354 C217,356 215,354 212,353 C209,352 194,345 189,344 C185,343 178,343 178,343 C178,343 175,342 172,340 C170,339 168,340 167,338 C166,335 168,335 168,333 C168,330 167,329 164,327 C161,324 161,324 156,324 C151,324 149,324 146,323 C144,322 143,321 143,319 C144,317 146,314 146,314 C146,314 153,309 153,306 C153,304 152,303 152,303 C152,303 154,299 158,297 C162,296 161,296 167,296 C172,295 176,299 178,300 C179,302 179,299 178,297 C176,296 171,292 171,288 C171,284 175,282 175,282 Z M175,282" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Setúbal" d="M178,343 C178,343 175,342 172,340 C170,339 168,340 167,338 C166,335 168,335 168,333 C168,330 167,329 164,327 C161,324 161,324 156,324 C151,324 149,324 146,323 C144,322 143,321 143,319 C144,317 146,314 146,314 C146,314 153,309 153,306 C153,304 152,303 152,303 C152,303 150,304 148,303 C147,301 148,300 146,299 C145,297 146,297 143,297 C140,297 140,298 139,301 C138,304 137,305 132,305 C128,305 124,303 124,303 L119,306 C119,306 116,308 117,309 C117,310 121,309 121,309 C121,309 124,310 124,310 C123,311 120,310 120,310 C120,310 120,312 119,312 C118,312 117,311 116,312 C115,312 114,312 115,313 C115,315 117,316 117,316 C116,317 115,315 114,314 C113,314 112,316 112,315 C111,315 112,313 111,312 C111,311 111,311 109,311 C108,311 105,311 105,311 C105,311 102,311 102,312 C102,313 107,321 107,324 C108,328 105,331 105,332 C105,333 105,334 107,334 C109,334 114,333 117,332 C121,331 128,325 128,325 C128,325 130,326 131,328 C132,328 133,329 134,329 C137,330 137,327 137,327 C137,327 136,325 136,324 C136,323 136,323 138,323 C139,323 137,323 138,325 C138,327 138,328 138,329 C138,330 137,329 138,331 C138,332 140,333 140,334 C139,334 135,332 134,332 C133,332 134,334 133,333 C133,333 129,328 127,328 C126,328 127,329 127,329 C127,329 132,335 134,339 C135,343 136,350 135,355 C134,360 128,375 128,375 C128,375 131,376 132,379 C134,381 134,384 134,384 L134,389 C134,389 136,388 138,390 C141,392 141,393 144,393 C146,393 154,385 156,385 C158,385 160,386 164,385 C168,385 168,381 169,375 C170,369 161,367 162,364 C163,360 165,359 172,356 C179,353 179,350 179,347 C179,345 178,343 178,343 Z M178,343" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Santarém" d="M124,299 C124,298 123,296 123,296 C123,296 126,289 127,288 C127,286 131,280 132,278 C133,275 134,276 132,272 C130,268 127,268 127,267 C127,266 133,266 133,264 C132,262 129,263 125,261 C121,258 120,255 120,255 C120,255 120,252 121,249 C122,247 126,241 128,240 C131,239 137,240 138,237 C140,235 144,224 144,223 C144,221 142,220 143,218 C143,216 143,215 146,212 C149,210 152,208 154,208 C156,208 157,214 161,214 C166,214 169,212 169,212 C169,212 173,221 174,223 C175,225 177,229 180,227 C184,226 184,222 184,220 C185,217 185,216 189,216 C193,216 191,220 194,223 C196,226 198,225 200,227 C201,229 201,234 201,234 C201,234 201,236 199,236 C197,235 199,233 194,233 C189,233 188,236 188,239 C188,242 190,242 190,245 C190,248 188,251 186,252 C184,254 174,263 174,263 C174,263 166,265 166,272 C166,280 175,282 175,282 C175,282 171,284 171,288 C171,291 177,296 178,297 C179,299 179,303 178,301 C176,299 172,296 167,296 C161,297 162,296 158,298 C154,300 152,303 152,303 C152,303 150,304 148,303 C147,302 148,300 146,299 C145,297 146,297 143,297 C140,297 140,298 139,301 C138,304 136,305 132,305 C128,305 124,303 124,303 C124,303 125,301 124,299 Z M124,299" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Beja" d="M134,389 C134,389 137,389 139,390 C141,392 141,393 144,393 C147,393 153,385 156,385 C158,385 160,385 164,385 C168,384 168,381 169,375 C170,369 161,367 162,364 C163,360 166,358 173,355 C180,352 179,350 179,347 C179,345 178,343 178,343 C178,343 185,343 190,344 C194,345 209,352 213,353 C216,354 218,355 223,353 C227,351 232,343 237,343 C241,343 242,349 244,351 C245,352 243,356 247,356 C251,356 251,355 251,355 C251,355 252,357 254,356 C255,355 259,352 261,352 C263,352 261,357 259,361 C258,365 258,368 256,369 C255,370 253,368 251,368 C249,369 250,370 248,371 C245,372 242,371 241,372 C239,374 240,377 239,381 C237,384 238,386 235,388 C232,390 233,389 229,394 C225,398 228,400 225,405 C222,410 222,413 222,413 C222,413 209,416 202,419 C194,422 187,431 183,431 C179,432 168,423 164,423 C160,423 160,427 156,427 C154,427 152,426 149,425 C146,425 142,425 140,425 C137,424 134,421 134,421 C134,421 135,419 134,414 C134,410 133,410 133,406 C133,402 135,398 135,398 C135,398 135,397 137,397 C138,398 138,399 138,399 C139,399 139,398 138,397 C138,396 137,396 136,396 C135,395 134,395 134,394 C133,393 134,392 134,392 L134,389 Z M134,389" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Faro" d="M222,413 C222,413 209,416 202,419 C194,422 187,431 183,431 C179,432 168,423 164,423 C160,423 160,427 156,427 C154,427 152,426 149,425 C146,425 142,425 140,425 C137,424 134,421 134,421 C134,421 133,424 131,427 C130,430 129,429 129,432 C129,434 129,433 129,437 C129,441 127,441 126,443 C126,445 127,445 125,448 C124,451 120,458 120,458 L124,462 C124,462 129,457 133,455 C136,454 140,455 142,454 C144,453 146,450 146,450 C147,449 149,451 149,451 L152,451 C152,451 152,449 153,449 C153,449 153,450 154,451 C155,452 158,454 158,454 C158,454 162,453 164,453 C166,453 169,455 169,455 C169,455 173,454 175,454 C177,454 181,454 182,455 C184,456 190,462 190,462 C190,462 191,460 192,460 C193,460 195,462 197,462 C198,462 200,459 201,458 C202,458 203,459 204,459 C205,459 213,453 213,453 C213,453 216,449 219,448 C221,446 225,445 225,445 L230,445 C230,445 229,440 228,438 C228,437 228,436 227,433 C227,430 228,428 227,427 C227,426 227,426 226,425 C226,423 226,421 226,420 C226,418 222,413 222,413 Z M222,413" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Açores" d="M71,185 C71,185 69,185 69,185 C68,185 68,184 66,184 C65,184 63,184 62,184 C61,184 56,180 56,179 C56,177 57,176 59,176 C61,176 62,179 66,180 C68,180 68,179 69,179 C70,179 70,180 71,180 C72,180 75,178 78,178 C82,178 82,178 83,180 C84,182 81,184 81,184 L77,184 L71,185 L71,185 Z M77,190 C77,190 79,190 80,192 C80,193 80,194 79,194 C77,194 78,194 76,193 C75,192 74,193 74,192 C74,190 75,190 76,190 L77,190 L77,190 Z M52,164 C56,164 55,164 57,165 C59,166 60,167 60,168 C60,170 58,172 57,172 C56,172 56,171 53,171 C50,171 47,169 47,167 C47,164 48,164 52,164 L52,164 Z M45,177 C45,177 43,177 41,176 C39,175 38,175 35,174 C31,172 26,169 26,168 C25,168 25,167 26,167 C26,167 29,168 32,170 C34,171 36,171 38,172 C43,175 45,176 45,177 L45,177 Z M35,156 C36,156 38,158 38,158 C38,159 38,160 36,160 C34,160 33,158 33,157 C32,157 33,156 35,156 L35,156 Z M25,176 C26,176 28,177 30,178 C32,180 37,181 38,182 C39,183 38,183 36,183 C35,183 35,182 33,182 C32,183 32,184 31,184 C30,184 30,183 29,183 C27,182 27,183 26,183 C24,182 25,183 23,182 C21,181 20,180 20,178 C20,176 21,176 22,176 C23,175 25,176 25,176 L25,176 Z M11,173 C12,172 12,172 13,172 C13,172 17,174 17,175 C17,176 15,177 14,177 C14,177 13,177 13,177 C12,177 12,177 11,177 C11,177 11,176 10,175 C9,174 8,175 8,174 C8,174 10,173 11,173 L11,173 Z M5,162 C6,161 6,160 7,160 C7,160 10,162 10,163 C10,165 8,168 7,168 C6,168 5,167 5,166 C4,165 4,165 4,164 C4,163 5,163 5,162 L5,162 Z M10,150 C10,149 12,150 12,151 C12,152 10,154 10,153 C10,153 10,150 10,150 L10,150 Z M10,150" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>
<path id="Madeira" d="M40,403 C40,403 42,403 43,404 C44,405 47,408 49,409 C51,409 56,409 56,410 C57,410 56,410 55,411 C54,411 54,411 53,411 C52,411 51,414 49,416 C48,418 47,419 46,419 C45,419 44,418 43,418 C41,418 42,419 40,419 C38,419 39,418 37,418 C35,418 35,418 33,417 C30,416 26,414 24,412 C20,409 19,407 19,405 C19,404 23,400 24,400 C24,400 28,404 30,405 C31,405 32,405 33,405 C35,405 34,404 37,404 C39,404 40,403 40,403 L40,403 Z M56,401 C56,401 58,400 58,401 C59,401 58,402 57,402 C56,402 56,401 56,401 L56,401 Z M65,388 C66,388 68,389 68,390 C69,391 68,392 68,393 C68,394 68,394 67,394 C66,394 66,394 65,394 C64,394 62,396 60,397 C59,398 59,399 58,399 C57,399 56,399 56,397 C56,396 57,397 58,394 C59,391 59,392 59,391 C60,391 63,388 65,388 L65,388 Z M53,397 C54,396 54,396 55,397 C55,397 54,398 54,398 C54,398 53,397 53,397 L53,397 Z M53,397" stroke="#94cae1" stroke-width="1" fill="#3a91c1"/>

            </g></svg></object>
```

Comment: See the code next, because code is too large to put in comment. Just can post code in 4 hours

Comment: In the path i have the stroke and the fill

Comment: Yes, but where is the javascript or SMIL code to **change** it.

Comment: I need that?? How can i create one? Please help me